# Munchkin "Insurance Rep" bad things

Tags: munchkin

I have the German version of the game so the card may be named differently in the original or might not exist at all. The card "Versicherungsvertreter" says under "bad things" that you lose items worth at least 1000 gold. If you don't have that much then you lose everything.

What does it mean by "lose everything"?

1. Lose all your items carried and still in your hand
2. Lose all your items and your entire hand
3. Lose every card in your possession
4. Lose every card and all your levels

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Items in your hand are safe from game effects unless explicitly targeted by the card description. I can't reach the rules from here, but that's made pretty clear - in the English rules, at least.

So my answer would be: **Lose all items currently in your character's possession, whether equipped or merely carried.**

Only **items** should be lost in this case - the character's class and race should be safe from the insurance industry.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I know what to look for I found it. All the way at the end of the rules. The German rules are horribly confusing. So the hand is safe but what about your current Class, Race, etc.?

Comment: @Kempeth - added more detail to address your further question.

Comment: character class and race do not qualify as "thing" thus would also be safe.  effects on the character such as diminished levels for the next fight, sex change etc would also remain unless they were granted by an item.

Comment: "The German rules are horribly confusing" - actually, the English ones aren't much better, at least in terms of organization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my copy of Munchkin on me, but I'm pretty sure it means lose all the items you are carrying.